# return classic ASP value via if statement into javascript

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am trying to set a value in javascript via ASP

```
foo('RequestMode', '<%=Request.Querystring("Mode")%>')
```

What I'd like to do is something like this

```
foo('RequestMode', '<%=if (Request.Querystring("Mode")="") then 
                            Session("RequestMode")=""
                       else
                            Request.Querystring("Mode")
                       end if%>')
```

If I use the opening tag

```
<%=
```

I get an error saying

> 'If' operator requires either two or three operands.

but if I use the opening tag

```
<&
```

I get an error saying

> Property access must assign to the property or use its value.
>
> Request.Querystring("Mode") <--- highlighted

Which makes me believe that there's no error with my code, per se. How can I accomplish my task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem should be the <%= that you are using with your if statement. What you are writing is actually printing that if statement directly to the page and not running it in VBScript. remember

```
<%= %>
```

is equivalent to

```
<% Response.Write() %>
```

So your if is being written to the page. what you should write instead is:

```
foo('RequestMode', '<% if (Request.Querystring("Mode")="") then %> 
                        <%= Session("RequestMode")="" %>
                   <% else %>
                        <%= Request.Querystring("Mode") %>
                   <% end if%>')
```

also as a note I left in what should be an error as I have no clue how you wanted to correct it. Specifically the line

```
<%= Session("RequestMode")="" %>
```

Should either be

```
<%= Session("RequestMode") %>
```

or

```
<% Session("RequestMode")="" %>
```

or

```
<%= Session("RequestMode") %>
<% Session("RequestMode")="" %>
```

or

```
<% Session("RequestMode")="" %>
<%= Session("RequestMode") %>
```

**Edit**

Just wanted to clarify the other error you mentioned. the reason it says

```
Property access must assign to the property or use its value
```

is because as the error states you are accessing a variable and doing nothing with it when you change <%= to <%

```
<%=Request.Querystring("Mode")%>
```

works fine because it actually reads

```
<% Response.Write(Request.Querystring("Mode")) %>
```

which will print the line to the page. When you remove the equals sign you are no longer performing an action on Request.Querystring("Mode") because you are removing that response.write